# SXA get data based on current year

Tags: sxa, content-search

I work on sxa Project where I have news Template, I trying to display all news items where the 
(News_Creation_date)field value in current year,
I created search Scope to retrieve data and Rendering Variants to display fields, but I can not add condition to get data based on Current year,how can I achieve that? [image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement in which I wanted any dates that have passed today to be excluded. I created a custom rule and added to the Item Query used by Page List.

Date Rule - You could update to check for the year instead of day.

```csharp
public class DateFieldPassedCondition<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)ruleContext, nameof(ruleContext));
        var item = ruleContext.Item;
        if (item == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FieldName)) return false;

        var fieldValue = item[this.FieldName];
        var endOfToday = DateTimeProvider.GetUtcNow().Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
        var fieldTime = DateUtil.ParseDateTime(fieldValue, DateTime.MaxValue).Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);

        if (fieldTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            Log.Warn(fieldValue, (object) this);
        }

        return endOfToday > fieldTime;
    }
}
```

---

[image: Rule entry]

---

In this example, I want to filter out events where the end date has passed (if not empty) or when the start date has passed.
[image: Item Query]

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the tokens that can be used in a search (scope). It requires some custom code, but it can be very powerful. I blogged about it: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html

How I did it (in short):

- create a class that overrides the `ResolveSearchQueryTokensProcessor`.
- override the TokenKey
- override the Process method: this is where you can define the logic for the query
- add you class at the (top of the) `resolveSearchQueryTokens` pipeline.

The Process method works with SearchStringModels. You should search for the one you defined (with the TokenKey) and replace that with a model that can be used for an actual query, something like:

```
return new SearchStringModel("custom", FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("{0}|{1}", name, value)))
  {
    Operation = "must"
  };
```

In your case you should create a model that matches the current year (value) to the date field. Would be easy if the date was only a year, but that is probably not the case. Not sure how to create the exact SearchStringModel for a date-year search though to be honest but you might be a (big) step closer to your solution now.